# Using non integer values as in a function

Tags: python, function, integer, typeerror

I'm getting this error: `'TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float'`
but the functions I'm using need to accept non integer values, otherwise my results are different...
Just to give you an idea, I have written some code that fits a gaussian to some data with a single peak. To do this, I need to calculate an estimated value for sigma. To get that, I've written two functions that are meant to look at the data, use the x value for the peak to find two points(r_pos and l_pos) which are either side of the peak and a set distance from the y axis (thresh). And from that I can get an estimated sigma(r_pos - l_pos).
This is all coming about from a piece of code that worked, but the mark sheet for my coursework says I need to use functions, so I'm trying to turn this:

```
I0 = max(y)
pos = y.index(I0) 
print 'Peak value is',I0,'Counts per sec at' ,x[pos], 'degrees(2theta)'
print pos,I0
#left position
thresh = 10
i = pos
while y[i] > thresh:
    i -= 1
l_pos = x[i]
#right position
thresh = 10
i = y.index(I0)
while y[i] > thresh:
    i += 1
r_pos = x[i]
print r_pos
sigma0 = r_pos - l_pos
print sigma0
```

Into something that uses functions that can be called etc. This is my attempt:

```
def Peak_Find(x,y):
    I0 = max(y)
    pos = y.index(I0)
    return I0, x[pos]

def R_Pos(thresh,position):
    i = position    
    while y[i] > thresh:
        i += 0.1
    r_pos = x[i]
    return r_pos

peak_y,peak_x = Peak_Find(x,y)
Right Position = R_Pos(10,peak_x)
```

peak_y = 855.0
Peak_x = 32.1 , by the way

Comment: I'm sure that you'll have about 6 comments in the next 5 seconds asking for code ;-), so I'll get that ball rolling -- Can you post the  code (a minimal example that demonstrates the problem) and expected inputs/outputs?

Comment: Even without seeing the code, I can tell you that you're using a float as a list index. Don't do that.

Comment: You'll need to tell us what the functions _do_ with those non-integer values, and _why_ you're trying to use them as an index, before we can tell you what you need to do to fix it. Maybe you need to use `int(x)` or `round(x)` as an index, or maybe you need to use a dict rather than a list, or maybe you need to write code to interpolate between values, or… How could we possibly know without having any idea what you're trying to do?

Comment: and what do you expect `y[32.1]` to return?!

Comment: If you need non-integer indices otherwise your results are wrong, you're storing your data wrong. Find a way to uniquely map your floating values to unique integer indices if you must use your intermediate results. For example, maybe something simple like multiply by 1000. If you're working with very precise values, you probably shouldn't even be using your results as an index.

Comment: If you're looking for values *between* your data points you need to look into *interpolation*. The simplistic method you're trying here has no chance of succeeding.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to replace the line

```
i = position
```

With something like

```
i = x.index(position)
```

because `position` is a float, and you want the location in the array of `position`.  You are using `i` to get the index of an array, and you **must** use `int`s to do this, hence using the `.index` method to return the (integer) location in the array.

---

You are better off writing the program this way because then the variable names will actually match what is contained in the variables.

```
def Peak_Find(x,y):
    I0 = max(y)
    pos = y.index(I0)
    return I0, pos

def R_Pos(thresh,position):
    while y[position] > thresh:
        position += 1 # Not sure if this is what you want
    r_pos = x[position]
    return r_pos # Not sure what you want here... this is the value at x, not the position
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The problem is that you can not index a sequence with a float, since an index is (in this case) by definition must be an integer.

Comment: @HannesOvrén If you read the part before the line break, I point out that you can't use `position` because it is a float, not an int.  Let me add a sentence to make it explicit that I am saying that.

Comment: Then why does your final piece of code do `y[position]` and `position += 0.1`?

Comment: Ah, I missed that.  Let me edit.  Probably should be an integer there too :)